# Spotfire Scripts not trusted

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am creating some Spotfire files where I use IronPython scripts to be able to export and import values from text files, on user demand. However when I relocate the Spotfire to someone else, the scripts cannot be executed.

When going to the action control, Script, Available Scripts, the scripts are there but there is a remark: 'Not trusted. Click edit...... and approve ...'. However others are not that familiar with scripting so I dont want them to go through this every time I send a new Spotfire file. Does anyone have experience here, or know how to pass the secrurity measure? Or make these steps simpler?

Source of security measure: http://stn.spotfire.com/stn/Configure/ScriptingIntroduction.aspx
"For security reasons you should always examine and approve a script that is not listed as trusted before executing it."

Any ideas are appreciated,

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are using Spotfire Server, ask your admin to add you to the **Script Authors** group. DXPs saved with scripts by members of this group will automatically be trusted.

note that this is regardless of being a member of the **Administrators** group; permissions of the **Script Authors** are not automatically granted to admins who are not also members; it is not a license-based permission like others. you can easily solve this by making the **Adminisrators** group a member of **Script Authors**.

N.B.: the **Author Scripts** license is not the same as being a member of this group, but obviously you have this license already!

EDIT: upgrading to Spotfire 7.0+ will improve the usability of trusting scripts, prompting users to trust the script as soon as the document is open.

Comment: Hi niko, thanks for your help, again. I tried to create a .dxp while being assigned to Script Authors group. When I send it to some one else (so other environment etc.) i encountered the same issue. And yes I had that license already. Could I be missing something?

Comment: As soon as you circumvent the spotfire server, you will run into this issue. Be glad it is there. Can you imagine the security risks if the scripts are allowed to run if they don't come from a trusted source?

Comment: phiver is correct. basically your server environment is considered a "trusted zone." consider that IP scripts have all of the rights your user account does. they can write/delete files, access network shares, run executables... it would be a nightmare :)
if you are using Spotfire 7.0, you should have a popup when you first open the document notifying the user that there are untrusted scripts and would he like to trust them. it definitely saves a few steps!

Comment: I understand that phiver is correct, but I was looking for something like you mentioned in Spotfire 7.0, a pop-up window or notification. You cannot expect normal users to go into the scripting :) Thanks for your feedback.